# Проблемы с кодировкой и загрузкой данных в файл excel на python

Tags: python, парсер, кодировка

```
    `len(l) != 0:

        with open(f'{names[count]}.csv', 'w', newline = '', encoding = 'utf-8') as file:

            writer = csv23.writer(file, delimiter = ';')

            writer.writerow(['Название', 'Цена'])`

            for a in l:

                writer.writerow([a['title'], a['price']])
```

При исполнении кода в excel файл загружается текст на непонятном языке, в непонятном формате. Без указания кодировки часть данных просто не загружается в файл (а именно цена  `a['price']`)

Comment: без utf-8 весь текст становится непонятным?

Comment: с использоваием encoding = 'utf-8' текст выглядит примерно так: РћС‚РґС‹С… РЎС‡Р°

Comment: Изначально весь текст на русском?

Comment: да, но с указанием кодировки превращается в непонятный бред

Comment: Тогда не указывайте кодировку utf-8, если до этого всё работает исправно

Comment: Без указания кодировки цена не отображается (читайте описание).